# CodeIgniter 4 : Form action refers to Error 404 Page

Tags: forms, codeigniter, routes, action

I'm new to CodeIgniter 4 and I guess I'm having trouble with routing.

I have created a basic login & register form however when I click on submit button, it refers me to 404 - File Not Found page. I couldn't figure it out by looking on documentation and searching online. Your help is much appreciated.

Here are my codes:

Controller > Home.php

---

```
 <?php namespace App\Controllers;
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data =[];
        helper(['form','url']);        
   
        echo view('header');
        echo view('anasayfa');
        echo view('footer');
        
    }

    public function adminlogin()
    {
        $data =[];
        helper(['form','url']); 
        
        echo view('login_header',$data);  
        echo view('adminlogin');  
        echo view('login_footer');  
    
    }
    
    public function register()
   {
       
        $data =[];
        helper(['form','url']); 
        echo view('login_header',$data);  
        echo view('register');  
        echo view('login_footer');  
    
  }        
    
}
```

app > Config > Routes.php

---

```
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('/adminlogin','Home::adminlogin');
$routes->get('/register','Home::register');
```

View > Register

---

```
<form action="<?=base_url('/register')?>" method="post">
<div class="form-group input-rounded">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" id="user_name"    placeholder="User Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-rounded">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"    placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-rounded">
        <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="user_password" id="user_password"  placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-rounded">
        <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="user_password_confirm" id="user_password_confirm"  placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    </div>
    <?php  if(isset($validation)):          ?>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" >
            <?= $validation->listErrors() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Create </button>
    <div class="signup-link">
        <p>Do You Have an Account?</p>
        <a href="adminlogin">Login</a>
    </div>  
    
</form>
```

View > adminlogin

---

```
<form action="<?=base_url('/adminlogin')?>" method="post">
    <div class="form-group input-rounded">
        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" id="user_name"    placeholder="User Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group input-rounded">
        <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="user_password" id="user_password"  placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" />Remember Me 
                <i class="input-frame"></i>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Sign In </button>
    <div class="signup-link">
        <p>Sign Up</p>
        <a href="register">Create Your Account Now</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

By the way, if I will try to navigate to localhost://mywebsite/public/adminlogin or localhost://mywebsite/public/register , it works flawlessly. I guess form action field is causing this issue. I tried to write "/adminlogin" instead of `"<?=base_url('/adminlogin')?>"` and "/register" instead of `"<?=base_url('/register')?>"` in to the form action field but did not make any difference. Also just "/" or blank form action field do not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a post route defined for that form. That’s why it shows you 404. You need to define a route for a post request.  You have the routes defined only for get. Thats why you can visit the page from your browser.

$routes->post('/login','Home::login');
$routes->post(‘/registerUser’, ‘Home::registerUser’);